# Get current position of a robot from a world file (Stage)

Tags: ros, roscpp, stageros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have C++ code where I am defining the behaviour of a group of robots. However right now the initial positions of each robots are defined in a .world file for the Stage simulation. Is there a way of possibly getting the position and theta defined in the .world file and referring to it in the C++ code?

I need some sort of way to set the following in the C++ code:

```
x = theXNumberDefinedInWorldFile
y = theYNumberDefinedinWorldFile
z = 0
theta = theAngleNumberDefinedInWorldFile
```

Sorry if this is hard to understand but I couldn't think of any other way of putting it as I'm still new to ROS. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40990/get-current-position-of-a-robot-from-a-world-file-(stage)/) by [Clefairy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3004/clefairy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-08-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you should be able to use:

```
math::Pose currentPose;
currentPose=world->GetModel(i)->GetLink("link_name_from_urdf")->GetWorldPose();
```

since i can change even when loading the same urdf file, you can find i by something like:

```
if (world->GetModel(i)->GetName().find("model_name_in_gazebo")!=std::string::npos) { }
```

check out the manipulating models world plugin [example](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/tutorials/plugins/model_manipulation_plugin) and the [math](http://gazebo.willowgarage.com/api/group__gazebo__math.html) page for some more info.

---

Originally posted by [mcevoyandy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2166/mcevoyandy/) with karma: 235 on 2012-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1